# How do I fix signup codes crashed?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
` Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  signUp() async {
  try {
    if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
      final UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      );

      if (userCredential.user != null) {
        // Registration successful, proceed with saving data to Firestore
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
          "name": nameController.text,
          "email": emailController.text,
          "password": passwordController.text,
        });

        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SignInForm(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (e is FirebaseAuthException) {
      if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text(
              "Email is already in use. Please use a different email.",
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
        );`
```

`When I run the app and enter email and password and then press the sign up, 
      'await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword('
      code becomes yellowand the crashed.
      How do I fix it?`

Comment: share your error message